# How to read files cloned by isomorphic-git on browser-side?

Tags: javascript, git, indexeddb, isomorphic-git

I've performed `git clone` command with isomorphic-git on browser-side. But I don't know where those files are stored and how to read those files with JavaScript.

Code snippet:

```
import { configure } from 'browserfs'
import { plugins, clone } from 'isomorphic-git'
import FS from '@isomorphic-git/lightning-fs'

configure({ fs: "IndexedDB", options: {} }, (err) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      window.fs = new FS("fs");
      plugins.set('fs', window.fs);

      (async () => {
        console.log(new Date())
        await clone({
          dir: '/',
          corsProxy: 'https://cors.isomorphic-git.org',
          url: 'https://github.com/isomorphic-git/isomorphic-git.git',
          singleBranch: true,
          depth: 1
        })
        console.log(new Date())
      })()
    })
```

Network activities observed by Chrome DevTools:

[image]

[image]

IndexedDB:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Detail tutorial here: https://isomorphic-git.org/docs/en/browser.html

You could try API from @isomorphic-git/lightning-fs operate files.

```
import LightningFS from '@isomorphic-git/lightning-fs'

const fs = new LightningFS('fs')
const pfs = fs.promises

const pck = pfs.readFile('/package.json')
const pckContent = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(pck)
console.log('pckContent', pckContent)
```